Pakistan Passport Expiring
My Pakistani passport is expiring on 18th Sep. I have already planned vacations from 3rd Oct onwards with my Employer and it is urgent for me to go to Pakistan as my wedding is planned in next week. My new passport is still not arrived. I have visited Consulate Office and they are saying they can offer 15 days extension in Passport Expiry Date at max. Now after 18th Sep, 15 Days means exactly on 3rd October same day when I am planning to go back. I want to know will there be any issue travelling to Pakistan on my last day of Passport Expiry. What can be possible scenarios to be faced on airport. I do not want to get it delayed.
P.S I have already applied for renewal but it is taking long time. I am not expecting it to be available till that time.

Which country do you live in and which one(s) do you plan to visit? Do note that not all countries accept passport expiry extensions.

You can put your exact details into https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm. See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153166/travelling-to-pakistan-with-expired-pakistani-passport . Note that even if you can legally enter Pakistan, the airline will likely not allow you to board with an expired Passport

Do you have another valid passport? Is there an option to have your renewal sped up by paying for it?

@ave it is clear from the question that the asker lives outside Pakistan and needs to travel to Pakistan.  Pakistan will surely honor an extended Pakistani passport.

@phoog their country of residence, however, might not let them return.

We do not know the OP's returning itinerary. A delay on an intermediate connecting flight, so the final arrival in Pakistan occurs the day after passport expiration, would very likely cause a denial of boarding for the final flight, even for a Pakistani citizen.

You're in trouble.
Here are my recommendations:

See if you can get a "fast-track" passport renewal. Most countries have the option to get a passport renewed in one or two days by paying an extra fee. Not all can do it outside the country. Call the embassy and see if you can convert your renewal to an urgent fast-track one. If you can then do it. Your problems will be over. This may cost a bit of money, but it's definitely better than not showing up at your own wedding.
If that is not possible, see if you can get an emergency passport. Embassies will sometimes issue these for lost passports, and you might be able to talk them into doing it in this case. Even if it will only work to get you to Pakistan, that's OK. You can get the renewed passport sent to you when it's done.
If that doesn't work, see if you can get your old passport back, ideally without stopping the renewal. If you can then bring your flight forward so that you fly out before it expires. If you can also get your passport extended (again preferably without stopping the renewal process) you may be able to use your original flight. However remember your passport has to be valid on the day you land, if that is different from the day you leave. These may be expensive, but remember it's better than missing your own wedding.
If any of those work then you will actually get to Pakistan for your wedding. Congratulations, all you have to do is get home. If you were able to keep the existing renewal process going, then get it delivered to your home and get someone you know to courier the passport out to you in Pakistan. If you had to stop the renewal to get your passport back then you will need to go and get your passport renewed in Pakistan. Pay whatever you need to get it done as fast as possible.

Many of these options are expensive, but in the long run a few thousand dollars isn't going to compare with the embarrassment of missing your own wedding. And it will be a great story to tell your grandchildren.
Finally, when you are done, please come and write your own answer here about what actually worked for you (or didn't work). This will help future readers.

What is the trouble?  If I understand correctly, the asker of the question is a Pakistani citizen who would be traveling to Pakistan with a valid Pakistani passport.  The fact that its validity would have been extended and that it would expire on the day of arrival should not cause insurmountable problems.  Also Indian law is very strictly against passports crossing borders without their bearers, and I would suspect that Pakistani law might have a similar view of it, given their similar legal history.
